# java.lang.NumberFormatException exception while starting spring mvc project

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbc

Here is spring bean that fails while creating I use value for url that provided by credentials page of https://console.run.pivotal.io site, where I trying to start it.

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
destroy-method="close">
<beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<beans:property name="url"
   value="jdbc:mysql://name:password@us-cdbr-iron-east-02.cleardb.net:3306/ad_c6046f48484b2d2" />
</beans:bean>
```

Here is stack

```
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory' defined in
> ServletContext resource
> [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init
> method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException:
> For input string: "password@us-cdbr-iron-east-02.cleardb.net"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JDBC URL is wrong. **JDBC URL FORMAT**: `jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<database_name>`

See this [link](http://razorsql.com/docs/help_mysql.html) of JDBC URL FORMAT for details.

So your correct configuration should be

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
destroy-method="close">
<beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<beans:property name="url"
   value="jdbc:mysql://us-cdbr-iron-east-02.cleardb.net:3306/ad_c6046f48484b2d2" />
<beans:property name="username" value="Your DB user name" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="Your DB Password name" />
</beans:bean>
```

**Note:** For username & password I have added two beans:property.

Comment: Matt Clark: url can be `jdbc:mysql://us-cdbr-iron-east-02.cleardb.net:3306/ad_c6046f48484b2d2?user=DB user name&password=DB password name`. It will also work. But the format he used for url that is wrong. But whatever I mentined that is cleaner way.

Comment: You are correct, I just dug through some of my source and do have `?user=user&password=pass`, my bad, faulty memory :D